# wpf edit item in listbox when a button is clicked somwhere on the form

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, listbox

Using [this question (Inline editing TextBlock in a ListBox with DataTemplate (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088909/inline-editing-textblock-in-a-listbox-with-data-template-wpf) I now have a `ListBox` that can be doubleclicked to edit the items in it. What I want now is to have a `Button` on the form, which when clicked will add a new item to the `ListBox` (this is easy), but then change the `ListBoxItem` into editmode, so the user can enter the value right away. How would you select the right `ListBoxItem`, and then find the `TextBlock` and `TextBox` inside it and change the visibility of them using the `SelectedIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really late answer for this, but have you considered adding `BeginEdit` and `EndEdit` methods to your items? You could then do something like:

```
CustomListBoxItem foo = new CustomListBoxItem();
customListBoxInstance.Add(foo);
foo.BeginEdit();
```

I had to do that with a couple of my custom controls that needed to be created and immediately enter edit mode. You'd end up with something like:

```
private void TextBlock1_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BeginEdit();
}

public void BeginEdit()
{
    // Code to put the item into edit mode.
}
```

I'd need to see some more code to give a more precise answer, but that's worked really well in my experience for controlling whether or not a control is in edit mode from outside the scope of that control.