# I am looking for DataGridTemplateColumn like functionality with CellEditTemplate ability, outside of DataGrid Control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am looking for about the same functionality like DataGridTemplateColumn has with ability to have Edit Mode.  but it should be hosted outside of DataGrid.

When you double click withing the control boundaries it should go to Edit Mode, When you click outside of it, it should go back to a display mode.

I was trying to accommodate DataGrid but it requires a collection as a source, In my case it is just one entity.

I was trying to create my own Control with different templates, but I run into an issue with switching it back to non edit mode when it being clicked outside of the control.

any ideas?

Comment: related question, how to create a Click-to-edit control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831796/click-to-edit-in-silverlight

Comment: So.. your question is solved?

Comment: Nope, I am looking for out of box control, or a good C# Code sample. The issue with Custom User Control is that it is a bit of a problem to catch LostFocus event.

Comment: The control you are describing sounds very special, so I think chances are very low for you to find one out-of-the-box. You have to write your own. I do this from time to time and never had problems like the one with the LostFocus event you are mentioning.

Comment: Do you have any working example for Templated ContentControl that utilizes LostFocus?

Comment: Yes I just created one to be sure. Can't post it as an answer though because it does not answer your original question. Maybe you post your solution as a new question where you state what issues with the LostFocus event your experience and I can see what might be wrong.

Comment: I just posted another question with my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613473/click-to-edit-control-lostfocus-event-issue. I hope it helps, Thanks